# Is there an iphone-like reminder app for ubuntu desktop?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, iphone, paid-applications

Is anyone aware of a [iphone-like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQNdLEh8Sjs) reminder app for Ubuntu?

Comment: What does the iPhone reminder app do?

Comment: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQNdLEh8Sjs) is what it does

Comment: You might want to describe it in words in your post if you want to reach a wider audience since not everyone uses an iPhone. Also, not everyone is going to watch a video that is almost 6 minutes long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something really similar and perhaps better. 
[reminders-app](https://launchpad.net/reminders-app).

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6stA3JpoFg).